# Trying to test Docusign demo key on production server before purchasing, is it possible?

Tags: python, docusignapi

Currently, I have a Docusign flow working on in development, but when I try to deploy it on my production server it fails.

```
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Length': '137', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '61275999-0e6f-4d16-925c-4f9f19c7800c', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Fri, 21 Jun 2019 17:31:10 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
HTTP response body: {
  "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"
}
```

I was hoping to be able to get it live to show it off. I have tried changing the base url from `https://demo.docusign.net` to `https://www.docusign.net` or `account-d.docusign.com` to `account.docusign.com`, but nothing.

So, this leads me to believe that a demo key just won't work at all.

Is there any way to work around this before purchasing an API plan?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to use that key in the DocuSign Production Environment, or your own internal Production environment?

Comment: @Drew my own internal production env

Comment: You should be fine to keep hitting Demo until you get a paid DocuSign account. Is your application failing to access your Sandbox account?

Comment: I believe so. I keep getting authentication failed on the live server, but testing it locally works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use an integrator key in the Production environment, it will need to pass the [Go Live process](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live), which requires a paid account to link the key to. This doesn't necessarily have to be an API plan - any paid account (Web or Enterprise) account will do.

Comment: Oh, I don't have any paid accounts at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can show off your integration by continuing to use the DocuSign demo system (developer sandbox).

The main restriction is that you can't use the demo system to create legally binding agreements. The production system does that.